# why is the column t.idsupplier not known?

Tags: mysql

Running the below query, the column **t.idsupplier** is not known

```sql
    select
      t.po_nomor
      , p.nama_supplier
      , p1.nama_barang
      , t.total
    from (select
            t1.po_nomor
            , (sum(t1.jumlah)-coalesce(t4.terima,0)) as total
          from pengiriman_supply t1
          inner join data_supplier t2 on t1.idsupplier = t2.id_supplier
          inner join data_barang t3 on t1.idbarang = t3.idbarang
          left join masuk t4 on t4.refrence = t1.po_nomor
          where t1.tanggal between date_sub(curdate(), interval 120 day) and curdate()
          group by t1.po_nomor) t
    inner join data_supplier p on t.idsupplier = p.id_supplier
    inner join data_barang p1 on t.idbarang = p1.idbarang
    order by t.po_nomor desc;
```

Answer (score 3):

**t** is the alias for

```
select
  t1.po_nomor
  , (sum(t1.jumlah)-coalesce(t4.terima,0)) as total
from pengiriman_supply t1
inner join data_supplier t2 on t1.idsupplier = t2.id_supplier
inner join data_barang t3 on t1.idbarang = t3.idbarang
left join masuk t4 on t4.refrence = t1.po_nomor
where t1.tanggal between date_sub(curdate(), interval 120 day) and curdate()
```

As the outer **select** includes **t.po_nomor** you probably forgot to include the column **idsupplier**.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.